# How to use both QTranslate & Gtranslate

Tags: wordpress, qtranslate

In wordpress woocommerce there is a single product page. Site is multilingual. The idea is to use automatic translation of the product non-translated content when needed only.
Now the situation is that GTranslate effects after website is loaded with content and then translates even translated product pages.
As I use woocommerce own single product template I don't know how to flag or how to get Google Translate know that this product name or translation is already translated...
Same thing with `<title>` tag - there is no possibility to put notranslate in it.
Any good suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use qtranslate and g-translate at same time. Qtranslate allow manual translation, and g-translate use automatic one.
Disable g-translate and translate your products by hand, the only clean solution i see. Qtranslate does not support automatic translation and is no longer updated. I recommand you [q-translate-x](https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-x/), that continue the developement of qtranslate or polylang (even better, for me).